# Makefile. Special chars

Tags: makefile

I have a question to this expression:

```
%.out: %.cpp Makefile
    g++ $< -o $@ -std=c++0x
```

What does it mean? I know, that it is defined target for *.o files but what does it mean `%.cpp Makefile` and `$<` and `$@`?

And:

What is differenece between:

```
all: $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))
```

and:

```
all: 
     $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))
```

The second doesn't works.

Comment: Unclear: "What is differenece between: -std=c++14*. What's that compiler flag doing at the end of the line? Please edit question to clarify.

Comment: Also, too broad. Post one question per question, and demonstrate your own effort - the meaning of the Make variables is a common FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question:

```
%.out: %.cpp Makefile
    g++ $< -o $@ -std=c++0x
```

This is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), and means: "for all files with a .cpp extension, compile (if needed) a corresponding .out file using the command `g++ $< -o $@ -std=c++0x`

In this line, `$<` is the prerequisite (the .cpp file) , `$@` is the name of the target (the .out file). [See here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

The rule also adds the makefile itself as a prerequisite, which means that all the files will be rebuild (even if they are already compiled) when you issue a `make target` command, if you make changes to the makefile.

For the second part of the question, your are mixing two things. A make rule is made of three parts:

```
target: dependencies
      commands
```

The second one you show cannot work because there is no command. The line just produces a bunch of filenames, that your shell cannot understand.

The first one adds to the list of dependencies all the object files, whose names are deduced from all the .ccp files. But you are missing a command, so nothing should happen (unless you didn't give us the whole rule ?)

**Edit**: ouch, missed something, this rule actually should work fine, as make will evaluate all the prerequisite targets, thus call the pattern rule described above. I got confused by the fact that this structure is usually written like this:

```
targetname: $(OUTFILES)
    @echo "- Done target $@"
```

with the variable defined above as:

```
OUTFILES = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))
```

or even as:

```
INFILES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OUTFILES = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(INFILES))
```

I suggest you find a good make tutorial, or [read the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), you seem to have lots of concepts to learn...